# Site Information as parameters into a Silverlight webpart

Tags: silverlight, web-part

We are designing a system with one site per customer.

We would like to have a silverlight webpart that shows customer information from a line of business application.

Is it possible for a Silverlight webpart to "know" which site it is on and then use the metadata of the site?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? If yes, could you post the answer?

Comment: @Kit, we ended up implementing this system in WPF instead of Silverlight/SP. But it would still be nice to know for future projects.